# How to get Tier Price of product magento2?

Tags: magento2, tierprice

How to get tier price of the product in Magento 2 with custom code?

This is my code

```
 public function getProductCollection()
    {
        $collection = $this->_productCollectionFactory->create();
        $collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
         $collection->setOrder('created_at', 'DESC');
        // $collection->setPageSize(3); // fetching only 3 products
        return $collection;
    }
```

and my call function in .phtml

```
  $productCollection = $block->getProductCollection();
   $productCollection->setPageSize(2);
            foreach ($productCollection as $product) {

 echo $product->getName();
 print_r($product->getTierPrice());
```

echo getName ,getPrice,getSpecial price works

but **getTierPrice** is not working.

ex. I have VIP member card (customer_group) I want to show tier price VIP member card to public not set all group
[image: I want to show tier price VIP member card]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can get the TierPrice as below.

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$product_obj = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load(1);                
$tier_price = $product_obj->getTierPrice();
if(count($tier_price) > 0){
    foreach($tier_price as $pirces){
        foreach ( array_reverse($pirces) as $k => $v ) {
            if($k == "price"){
                $tp = number_format($v, 2, '.', '');
                echo $tp;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`$product_obj` have a product data please check or debut it you can know. It will work 100%. see my log pic below.

[image]

Create constructor in your class and initiate the class object. From that Object you can do stuff.

Comment: it blank page when i run your code
not echo tier price

Comment: @tttk see my updated answer.

Comment: sorry sir,do you have full code to echo tier_price ?

it here my code

 foreach($tier_price as $pirces){

 echo $prirces["price"];
    //get the each one
    
  
    }

Comment: @tttk now try my code.

Comment: what is array_reverse($tier) ? Variables $tier?

Comment: ok it work but i want to show tier_price only my customer group
not set all group

Comment: ex.i have vip member card(customer_group) i want to show tier price vip member card to public

Comment: @tttk see updated answer. you can assign `$tp` amount to card.

Comment: @tttk I think you are asking something different than this. You can ask separately so that you can get the answer for that.

Answer (score 7):

To get the tier price for the customer groups, use **getTierPrices()** instead of **getTierPrice()**. Please see the example code below:

```
<?php
use \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;
include('/www/magento2.1/app/bootstrap.php');

$bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
$objectManager = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();

$state = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Framework\App\State');
$state->setAreaCode('frontend');

$productId = 1;
$product_obj = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($productId);

getAnyGroup($product_obj);

function getAnyGroup($product_obj) {
    $tier_price = $product_obj->getTierPrices();

    if(count($tier_price) > 0){
        echo "price_qty\tprice\tCustomerGroupId\n";

        foreach($tier_price as $price){
            echo $price->getQty();
            echo "\t";
            echo $price->getValue();
            echo "\t";
            echo $price->getCustomerGroupId();
            echo "\t";
            echo "\n";
            print_r($price->getData());
            echo "\t";
            echo "\n";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Works for me in Obsever

Comment: how to get all product with tier price. I want to show all the product hv tier price in different page

Comment: @Daniel_12, can we get the product price using customer group id?

Answer (score 0):

code from Bojjaiah works but it shows the tier prices like this: "2,252,132,001,88". How can I put them like this: Buy 1 for 2,52 / Buy 2 for 2,13 / Buy 3 for 2,00 / Buy 4 for 1,88? Thank you!

This is the original code from Bojjaiah:

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance(); $product_obj = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load(1); $tier_price = $product_obj->getTierPrice();if(count($tier_price) > 0){
foreach($tier_price as $pirces){
    foreach ( array_reverse($pirces) as $k => $v ) {
        if($k == "price"){
            $tp = number_format($v, 2, '.', '');
            echo $tp;
        }
```